# Using TF package to transform rotations

Tags: ros, gazebo, coordinate-system, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the Gazebo simulator and gazebo_ros to interface with it. It the simulator, I have a "quadcopter" object. I would like to apply a thrust to the quadcopter. Gazbo_ros offers a way to apply a force to an object, but it can only do so in the world's coordinate frame (i.e. even if my quadcopter is on its side, applying a force in the Z axis will still make it go directly vertical).

I'm trying to figure out how to use the TF package to transform between the two coordinate frames. Essentially, with a given Pose vector and Quaternion orientation of the quadcopter model, how can I convert from the quadcopter's Z axis to a vector in the world's coordinate frame? i.e. what force vector in the world's coordinate frame should be applied to give a force in the quadcopter's Z axis?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206766/using-tf-package-to-transform-rotations/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out, using the tf::Quaternion class which comes with built-in vector transformations.

---

Originally posted by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) with karma: 113 on 2015-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This TF tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) will be a good starting point; it listens to the TF topic and calculates the requested transform in the `listener.lookupTransform` call.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1